# Download Fortify export data using the API

Tags: javascript, api, fortify

**Objective**

To generate CSV "export data" files from within Fortify, then download them.

**Steps**

1. Generate the (csv) export data using, that works fine:

> https://SERVER:8443/ssc/api/v1/dataExports/action

2. Download the csv file using:

> https://SERVER:8443/ssc/transfer/reportDownload.html - GET

**Problem**

I'm facing an issue with step 2, export being successfully generated. I can't seem to download them.

I'm requesting :

> https://SERVER:8443/ssc/api/v1/fileTokens

with the payload : *{ fileTokenType : "REPORT_FILE" }*

I obtain:
*YzFmOWY4ZjMtZjU2MS00ZTU0XXXXXXXXXXXXX*

Yet as per the documentation, I should get something like: 
*7e8d912e-2432-6496-3232-709b05513bf2*

As a result when I attempt to GET my file with the following request:

> https://SERVER:8443/ssc/transfer/reportDownload.html?mat=YzFmOWY4ZjMtZjU2MS00ZTU0XXXXXXXXXXXXX&id=449741

I get a 500 error.

**Questions**

- What do you guys get when you request: https://SERVER:8443/ssc/api/v1/fileTokens?
- Is the documentation not exactly correct?
- If not, what do you reckon I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, the correct link is

```
dataExportDownload.html
```

instead of:

```
reportDownload.html
```